# Trouble running my python selenium script using proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, proxy

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to fetch a text block from a webpage in which it is written that my scraper is sending request via proxy or not.

For example: if the request is not sent via proxy then text should appear in the console is like `'This request appears NOT to have come via a proxy.', 'The request appears to have originated from ip address [my_ip_address]'` which is what I'm having.

How can I run my scraper through proxy? Thanks in advance.

Script I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://163.172.27.213:3128',
    'https': 'https://163.172.175.210:3128'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy_arg = ';'.join(['{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()])
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="{}"'.format(proxy_arg))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test')
items = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".main-panel p")[:2]]
print(items)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

proxy = "12.12.12.12:1212" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://www.google.com")
```